# Test write(to: url) in Swift

Tags: swift

I have a function that uses

```
func write(to url: URL, atomically useAuxiliaryFile: Bool, encoding enc: String.Encoding) throws
```

Such that :

```
func writeString(string: String, withDestinationFileName dest: String, withSubDirectory: String = ""){
        _ = createDirectory(toDirectory: directory, withSubDirectoryPath: withSubDirectory)
        if let fullDestPath = buildFullURL(forFileName: dest, withSubDirectoryPath: bundleName, inDirectory: directory)
        do {
            try string.write(to: fullDestPath!, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
        } catch let error {
            print ("error\(error)")
        }
```

}
    }

Usually to test file functions I using mocking and stubbing, for example I've just written a mock for Filemanager.default.

However here we have an instance method on NNString ([Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsstring/1407654-write)), so what would we do?

Options:

1. Inject a mock for NSString
2. Not test this function
3. Rewrite the function so it returns a Bool, and check the result
4. Inject the .write function through the function signature and replace
   Or another option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, that the best approach will be to use protocol:

```
protocol WriteableString {
    func write(to url: URL, atomically: Bool, encoding: String.Encoding) throws
}

extension String: WriteableString {}

class MockWriteableString {
    var url: URL?

    func write(to url: URL, atomically: Bool, encoding: String.Encoding) throws {
        self.url = url
        //...
    }
}
```

and change your function to:
`func writeString(string: WriteableString, withDestinationFileName dest: String, withSubDirectory: String = "")`

With this approach you test your function and also check for example if `url` passed to `write(to:atomically:encoding)` function is good.